# FlaskRestPlus how to have an optional parameter in the url

Tags: python, swagger, flask-restful, flask-restplus

I'm new to Flask and Flask-RestPlus. I'm creating a web api where I want keep my `POST` urls different from the `GET` urls which are visible in Swagger. For example in Flask-Restplus

```
@api.route('/my_api/<int:id>')
class SavingsModeAction(Resource):
    @api.expect(MyApiModel)
    def post(self):
        pass #my code goes here

    def get(self, id):
        pass #my code goes here
```

So in swagger for the both apis url would look like

> GET: /my_api/{id}
>
> POST: /my_api/{id}

But so far I have absolutely no use of `{id}` part in my post api and it perhaps creates a bit of confusion for an user whether to update an existing record or to create a new, however the purpose of the api is just to create.

The other problem is `id` now a mandatory field al lest from swagger.